# Type-hinting a tuple without being too verbose

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there a way to type hint a tuple of elements without having to define each inner element a bunch of times?

Example:

```py
a = ((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5))

a: Tuple[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int]]
```

I am looking for something that may look like this

```py
a: Tuple[5*Tuple[int, int]]
```

as otherwise my code would become very verbose in order to indicate something like that (tuple containing 5 tuples of 4 ints)

Comment: No, you either have to be explicit or declare it as variable length: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple. Note you can extract the inner type, though, e.g. `XY = Tuple[int, int]` then `a: Tuple[XY, XY, XY, XY, XY]`.

Comment: Not really clear to me, but maybe you can consider something like `tuple((1, 2) for _ in range(5))`?

Comment: @iGian what I'm looking for, is type hinting the variable and being 100% explicit, but without having to be too verbose

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right, extracting the inner type was my fallback solution if nothing better can be done :)

Comment: At this point you should probably just use a named tuple or frozen dataclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few options here. (All examples here assume `a = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8))`, i.e., a `tuple` consisting of 4 `(<int>, <int>)` tuples.)

You could, as has been suggested in the comments, just use a type alias for the inner type:

```
from typing import Tuple

X = Tuple[int, int]
a: Tuple[X, X, X, X]
```

You could also use a type alias for the whole annotation if it's still too long, perhaps using `typing.Annotated` to clarify what's going on in your code:

```
from typing import Tuple, Annotated

X = Tuple[int, int]

IntTupleSequence = Annotated[
    Tuple[X, X, X, X],
    "Some useful metatadata here giving "
    "some documentation about this type alias"
]

a: IntTupleSequence
```

You could also use `typing.Sequence`, which is useful for if you have a homogenous sequence (that may be mutable or immutable) that's either of indeterminate length or would be too long to feasibly annotate using `typing.Tuple`:

```
from typing import Sequence, Tuple

a: Sequence[Tuple[int, int]]
```

You can achieve the same thing as `Sequence` by using `Tuple` with a literal ellipsis. The ellipsis here signifies that the tuple will be of indeterminate length but homogenous type.

```
from typing Sequence, Tuple

a: Tuple[Tuple[int, int], ...]
```

I prefer using `Sequence` to using `Tuple` with an ellipsis, however. It's more concise, seems like a more intuitive syntax to me (`...` is used to mean something similar to `Any` in other parts of the `typing` module such as `Callable`), and I rarely find there's anything gained by telling the type-checker that my immutable `Sequence` is specifically of type `tuple`. That's just my opinion, however.

A final option might be to use a `NamedTuple` instead of a `tuple` for variable `a`. However, that might be overkill if all items in your tuple are of a homogenous type. (`NamedTuple` is most useful for annotating heterogeneous tuples.)